# Azure Devops can't delete backlog option, with project admin

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps I have a project administrators Group. It has permissions set for all but

Delete shared Analytics views &
Edit shared Analytics views

are allowed.

There is a Team as well as Areas setup where the project admins group are members....

Many in the project admin group can create backlog items (epics, features etc) but the do not have the option to delete them?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, the user has been added to the Project Administrators group. In order to solve the problem, please check the following things:

1. Go to Organization Settings-> Users under General, then check and make sure that users with **Basic** access or higher, not Stakeholders access.
2. Go to Project Setting-> Permissions under General -> Click enter Project Administrators group-> switch to Members tab, click on the user to enter the next page, make sure the **Delete and restore work items** permission is set to Allow.
   [image]
3. Select the work item in the backlog tab, click More action, and then click Delete.
   [image]

For more information, see [default permissions and access for Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/permissions-access-boards?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thank you.. i never looked at the user account settings.. they were set to stakeholder